# R: How to select columns in a data table depending on column variance?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I normally use dataframes for working, but recently trying to get a hang of Datatables for speed purposes. They're incredibly useful for some recent files.

Anyway, I have a function that I use to calculate column variance and remove from my dataframe, once I have already read it in.

```
rm_invariant_cols = function(df) {

     df = df[, sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))>1)]   ## takes cols with one unique value and drops
     return(df)

}
```

How can I achieve this when `df` is a datatable? When I run the same function on a data table I get a collection of logicals for each column rather than the columns themselves.

NB. I have read the vignette, which doesn't seem to cover this.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `with=FALSE`:

```
dt <- data.table(A = 1:3, B = c(1,1,1), C = c(2,1,3), D = c(2,2,2))

dt
#   A B C D
#1: 1 1 2 2
#2: 2 1 1 2
#3: 3 1 3 2

dt[, sapply(dt, uniqueN) > 1, with=FALSE]
#   A C
#1: 1 2
#2: 2 1
#3: 3 3
```

Or maybe a more idiomatic way as suggested by @thelatemail:

```
dt[, .SD, .SDcols=lapply(dt, uniqueN) > 1]

#   A C
#1: 1 2
#2: 2 1
#3: 3 3
```

Comment: @thelatemail Greate idea. That looks more like the idiomatic way to deal with the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. Solved the problem although the syntax is still baffling in many ways.

Comment: PS as a comment, I used `microbenchmark` on the `uniqueN` versus just using the simpler `length(unique(x))` version, and BTW it seems a lot quicker to stick with `length(unique()`.

Comment: @JohnL_10 interesting. Thanks for sharing the benchmark result.

Comment: A known issue re the speed, fwiw https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1120